# H2 "OTHER" data type throws Exception when storing String or Boolean

Tags: h2

I understand that the OTHER data type can store any Serializable object. However when I try to store an instance of String or Boolean it fails with an exception.

Is this a misunderstanding on my part, or a bug in H2?

Here's repro code.

```
import org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test");

        conn.createStatement().execute("drop table if exists test;");
        conn.createStatement().execute("create table test (key VARCHAR, value OTHER)");
        testInsert(conn, "key1", "foobar");
        testInsert(conn, "key2", Boolean.TRUE);
        testInsert(conn, "key3", new MyClass("foobar"));
        conn.close();
    }

    private static void testInsert(Connection conn, String key, Serializable value) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into test (key, value) values (?, ?)")) {
            statement.setString(1, key);
            statement.setObject(2, value);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Insert of value={" + value + "} succeeded");
        } catch (JdbcSQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Insert of value={" + value + "} failed: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class MyClass implements Serializable {
        private final String s;

        public MyClass(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a stack trace when I try to store String in the OTHER column:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "foobar"; SQL statement:
insert into test (key, value) values (?, ?) -- (?1, ?2) [90004-188]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.util.StringUtils.convertHexToBytes(StringUtils.java:983)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:867)
    at org.h2.table.Column.convert(Column.java:148)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:143)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:78)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:157)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at com.barbarysoftware.pokercopilot.ScratchSpace.testInsert(ScratchSpace.java:29)
    at com.barbarysoftware.pokercopilot.ScratchSpace.main(ScratchSpace.java:19)
```

Comment: Did you try using `statement.setObject(2, value, Types.OTHER)`?

Comment: @ThomasMueller thanks, that solved the problem!