# how to insert object to h2

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

I've read H2 docs about storing objects in database. There is special SQL type OTHER and methods `setObject` and `getObject`. I've tried this code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.foo (name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, data OTHER NULL);");
    statement.execute();
} finally {
    statement.close();
}

statement = null;

try {
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PUBLIC.foo (name, data) VALUES(?,?);");
    statement.setString(1, "lololo");
    statement.setObject(2, new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
    statement.execute();
}finally {
    statement.close();
}
```

But I've got the exception:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ð¨ÐµÑ�Ñ‚Ð½Ð°Ð´Ñ†Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ€Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ð°Ñ� Ñ�Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¾ÐºÐ° Ñ�Ð¾Ð´ÐµÑ€Ð¶Ð¸Ñ‚ Ð½ÐµÑˆÐµÑ�Ñ‚Ð½Ð°Ð´Ñ†Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ€Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ�Ð¸Ð¼Ð²Ð¾Ð»Ñ‹: "(foo, bar)"
>   Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "(foo, bar)"; SQL statement:
>   INSERT INTO PUBLIC.foo (name, data) VALUES(?,?) -- (?1, ?2) [90004-191]

What is wrong?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964209/h2-other-data-type-throws-exception-when-storing-string-or-boolean

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you were look for (Even I was).

You just need to create a column in your table with type as '**other**'. 
See '**create table testobj2(obj other)**'

Look at my Sample code :

```
    static String DB_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    static String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:h2:./test2";
    static String DB_USER = "";
    static String DB_PASSWORD = "";

    public static void benchmarkH2Inserts()   {
        try {
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            String createQry = "create table testobj2(obj other)";
            String insertQuery = "insert into testobj2(obj) values(?)";
            String selectQuery = "select * from testobj2";

//            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            dbConnection.prepareStatement(createQry).executeUpdate();
            long lStartTime = System.nanoTime();

            for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
                CloudElement_Circuit obj = new CloudElement_Circuit();
                obj.setNrm8DesignId(1230L);

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
                preparedStatement.setObject(1,obj);
                preparedStatement.execute();
                dbConnection.commit();
            }
            long lEndTime = System.nanoTime();
            long output = lEndTime - lStartTime;
            System.out.println("benchmarkH2Inserts() : Elapsed time in nanoseconds: " + output);
            System.out.println("benchmarkH2Inserts() : Elapsed time in milliseconds: " + output / 1000000);

            //Selecting
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())    {
                CloudElement_Circuit obj = (CloudElement_Circuit) rs.getObject("obj");
                System.out.println("Fetched Object : " + obj.getNrm8DesignId());
            }

            dbConnection.close();

        } catch (Exception e)   {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note that 'CloudElement_Circuit' is a Serialized class.
Look at 'OTHER Type' here : http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html
H2 Example : https://www.javatips.net/blog/h2-database-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
List<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
String comma="";
 StringBuilder allGenres = new StringBuilder();
 for (String g: genre) {
    allGenres.append(comma);
    allGenres.append(g);
    comma = ", ";
 }
```

Then you can pass it like this

```
preparedStmt.setString (2, allGenres.toString());
```

Comment: So, how  can I insert any type to one field? String, Int, List of Objects etc. ? I need to insert any Object to db.

Comment: You can use Serialization. Check out thiis page ,they have a nice example.[java2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/HowtoserializedeserializeaJavaobjecttotheMySQLdatabase.htm)